# Flurry Ad server responded with the following error(s): Unknown Api Key, for Android App

Tags: android, ads, flurry

In Android, to show Ads from the Flurry platform, the procedure was to register the current App, and then setup new ad units like Banners, Native Ads, Rewarded Videos, etc. in the Flurry page.

Now when you enter the Flurry site to manage Ads, you get the following warning:

*The functionalities to set up new ad units and change existing ad units have been discontinued*

So Flurry recently disabled the creation or modification of their ad units, and apparently didn't implement any new procedure in their code or in their system. The obvious result is that I had setup Flurry Ads that used to deliver Ads normally, and now, I get no Ads at all, being the Log message:

**Ad server responded with the following error(s): Unknown Api Key**

Am I missing something? A big mistake? Any workaround? Thanks.

Comment: Any solutions here? I just started with them and I am having a similar issue. When tapping on "monetization" to set the Ad Units I get a message saying "We have discontinued the self-serve option". I don't understand what it is going on...

Comment: Hi. I just deleted Flurry from my App and moved on. They don't even bother to answer the e-mails from developers. Now I use Appodeal and Smaato. I have already managed to get ads rolling from them, so their platform and instructions just work. Appodeal has even a REAL support chat, which makes a huge difference for novice developers like me. Saludos

Comment: Saludos amigo. How are Appodeal and Smaato? I just started with inmob.com, let's see how it goes. Do you know of any page that people talks about the different options with real values to compare each service?

Comment: Hola. You get numerous pages when googling: "Best mobile ads 2019". I just use the ranking pages to know the names of the companies offering the ads. But to really know who you would be dealing with, just google: "scam" + the name of the company. If the company has been dishonest or problematic or low-paying, there will be pages with forums where developers tell their horror stories. With this method, the clean ones for me were: Appodeal, Smaato, Flurry, Mopub, Facebook. I like Appodeal because it has real time chat, they pay fine, you can fulfill the ad spaces with ads from other companies...

Comment: and I like Smaato because they have continuous video ads, have multiple options for banners, the ads run fine, have fulfillment with ads from multiple sources and the payment could be reasonable. I hope this helps. Suerte (luck)

Comment: Finally, a page with comparison of fees is improbable and inaccurate because there are numerous factors that affect the amount that they pay: ad type, fulfillmnet rate (most of the time empty or full space), if the ads pay per eCPM or only clicking (like Google's Admob, which I dislike), country where the ads run, type of contents in the ads, algorithm used by the company to calculate rates, etc.